# In App Subscription : Purchase Status API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, purchase-order

I want to use the Google's Purchase status API, to check the status of the purchased subscription at any time.

Here is what I am using :-

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/my_package_name/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/purchases/my_purchase_token

where my_package_name - name of my package
my_subscription_id - subscription_id
my_purchase_token - my purchase token of a valid purchase

But, it always give the following in response:-

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I am unable to get what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Calls to the Google Play Android Developer API require authorization. Google uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol to allow authorized applications to access user data. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html

Comment: @xDragonZ I have made the Refresh Tokens, Access Tokens. Now what to do with these tokens ?? There is no information available on internet ??